# Angular wont update view even after $apply was used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am including an html file using inside my main page using

```
<div ng-controller="detailViewCtrl"  ng-include="'partials/template.html'"></div>
```

inside this script there is a list showing some documents.

```
<li ng-repeat="document in relatedDocuments" style="cursor: pointer;" class="box" ng-click="gotoDocument(document)">
  <div><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> <span>{{document.name | limitTo: 20 }}{{document.name.length > 20 ? '...' : ''}}</span></div>
  <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
    {{document.name}}
  </md-tooltip>
  <thumbnail file-type="{{document.filetype}}" source="document.fullpath" max-height="150" max-width="210"></thumbnail>
</li>
```

At some point using a button that is inside another template, is included in pretty much the same way, I might upload a new pdf file. The file is uploaded to my server and a query is made requesting the documents list (that is now expected to contain this new document). This query is in the same function that is initially called to fill `relatedDocuments`. This time though the list does not update, no matter how many documents I upload. Only if I refresh I will see the newly uploaded files.

Trying to force a `$digest` myself will not have any effect, and my view will remain unchanged even though I can see the printed list in my console after the promise is resolved.

The controller looks like this:

```
.controller('detailViewCtrl', function($scope, $i18next, $routeParams,...    

$scope.relatedDocuments = [];

$scope.getRelatedDocuments = function(document) {
  myAPI.getRelatedDocuments($scope.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.relatedDocuments = response.data.result;    
    console.log("getRelatedDocuments", $scope.relatedDocuments);
  });
};

$scope.getRelatedDocuments();
```

Also inside this module there is an `uploadDocument()` function that after it uploads a document it calls `getRelatedDocuments()`. This function uses [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to deal with the actual data transfer to the server.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: tempPath,
      method: 'POST',
      file: file,
      sendFieldsAs: 'form',
      fields: {
        docid: $scope.id
      }
    });

    file.upload.then(function(response) {
      $timeout(function() {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.getRelatedDocuments(); // Here I try to update the list
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function(evt) {
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
  }
```

This upload function is called after the corresponding button is pressed somewhere in the main page. Since I can see the log message, and the response I assumed that everything goes as should.

A plunk that contains the relevant parts of the code can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HefUquIQAfwr2kf5hiHx?p=preview). It does not work of curse since it needs the backend to save and get the documents list, but it's a good reference still.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post some code of `detailViewCtrl`? And also, maybe you try to have `$watch` function to detect the change and then use `$apply()` function.

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: I know its actually really useful in these sort of questions to provide an example but in this case I am not sure I can, since I've added quite a few things and there are stuff like the call to my server that I cant replicate in a simple plunk. I hoped it was some mistake I made with the way I include the template or the asynchronous call, because in the past I never had an issue with my page updating on a model change. All the code that is related to the issue is included though.

Comment: Also do note that the log statement correctly prints on time the new list, so there is no issue with the variable not having the needed data.

Comment: You should provide a mock, instead of $http.post.then, use directly: $q.when(mockedValue)

Comment: can you provide `getRelatedDocuments` function?

Comment: Its provided in the above code `$scope.getRelatedDocuments` and then called immediately after so the list can be created when the page loads.  I am working on a plunk that should help, just as soon as I find a way to emulate `ng-file-upload` and Hitmands's suggestion.

Comment: @dearn44, here all work http://plnkr.co/edit/I0AK69ayczVmQEFtm28I?p=preview

Comment: myAPI is simply a function inside a factory that returns `return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: testurl,
          data: postdata
        });`

Comment: @Grundy thanks for the plunk, this will teach me how to provide working examples for my next questions. The thing with this though is that indeed the list is displayed successfully in my code also (It's exactly as your plunk). This will happen only the first time though. The time that `getRelatedDocuments` is called directly. All the times that i call it after the new file is uploaded though, by calling it after the upload is done, it refuses to update. Would the upload function be relevant?

Comment: sure, how you upload? also add in OP that use `ng-file-upload`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94422/discussion-between-grundy-and-dearn44).

Comment: An edit was made pointing to a plunk that better illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I should not had used the ng-controller directive when including the two templates since they are called from a page that also uses the same controller. If you have the same controller nested onto itself then Angular may behave on unexpected ways.